# Trying to download a instance of "Blob" created from "new Audio().buffer" but the file is strange

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a small app where it's possible to listen to a distorted preview of a recording. After that it should be possible to download it.

My playSound function works as expected and then I try to return the "source" which is just an instance of the Audio class so I can later download it.

```
let audioCtx;
let source;
let myBuffer;
let songLength;
let request;

function playSound(
  file,
  speed = 1,
  pitchShift = 1,
  loop = false,
  autoplay = true
) {
  if (pitchShift) {
    audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", file, true);

    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    request.onload = function () {
      var audioData = request.response;

      audioCtx.decodeAudioData(
        audioData,
        function (buffer) {
          myBuffer = buffer;
          songLength = buffer.duration;
          source.buffer = myBuffer;
          source.playbackRate.value = speed;
          source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
          source.loop = loop;
        },

        function (e) {
          "Error with decoding audio data" + e.error;
        }
      );
    };

    request.send();
    source.play = source.start;
  } else {
    source = new Audio(file);
    source.playbackRate = speed;
    source.loop = loop;
  }
  if (autoplay) {
    source.play();
  }
  return source;
}
```

When the playSound function is called I attach the returned source to the window.audioSource so I am able to download it later

```
document.getElementById("preview").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const audioSource = playSound("test.mp3", (pitch = 0.5));

  // Save the audio source for later use
  window.audioSource = audioSource;
});
```

Then in the "Download" event listener I try to finally turn the buffer of the audioSource into a blob and download it. It seems to work until I try to play the file where it complains about the format not being correct.

```
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Check if there's an audio source
  if (window.audioSource) {
    const audioBlob = new Blob([window.audioSource.buffer], {
      type: "audio/mp3",
    });
    console.log(audioBlob);

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

    // Create a download link and trigger a click to download the file
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "downloaded_audio.mp3";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
});
```

When I try to console.log the blob it seems the size is pretty small so I am guessing this is where everything goes wrong.

```
Blob {size: 20, type: 'audio/mp3'}size: 20type: "audio/mp3"[[Prototype]]: Blob
```

Comment: Have you tried reading those 20 bytes in notepad ? What does they look like ?